# How to get new csv files from gcs buckets using python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have csv files present in <gcs_bucket_name>/store_nlp/ folder in GCS buckets.
I want to get updated csv file from this folder depending on recent time/date
My current code is as follows
store_input_folder='store_nlp'

```
str_files = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=store_input_folder)
storefileList = [file.name for file in str_files if '.csv' in file.name]
if len(storefileList) == 1:
    store_updated_file=storefileList[0]
elif len(storefileList) > 1:
    store_updated_file=storefileList[len(storefileList)-1]
else:
    log.info("Currently no new store file present in Folder")
```

But I am not getting updated csv as per the time and date

Comment: Does this answer helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58659104/19378826

Comment: No@NestorCenizaJr

Comment: What's the pattern of your CSV file name?

Comment: pattern is like ca_customer_store_week_number_2023.csv , but regardless of pattern/name I want new csv uploaded to that folder which will be on weekly basis @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Your code is correct but you can't assume that the file are correctly ordered in Cloud Storage (even if, most of the time, they are). So you should programmatically filter on the CSV file name to extract the week number and, at the end, take only the highest (for the highest year also)